# Increasing storgage size of Windows 7 VM on Ubuntu 16.04 host

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vdi

I have a `Windows7` virtual machine running on Ubuntu 16.04 host. I ran out of hard disk space on my Windows guest. I tried resizing the disk size from my host as follows

```
VBoxManage modifyhd Win7-64bit.vdi --resize 66070
```

Initially the size of the `vdi` file was  `56070M`.

However when I open the virtual machine settings and go to Storage settings this is what I see.[image: Storage]

The Virtual Size has actually increased to `64.52 GB`. However Actual Size has not (it is still `54.95 GB`)

What is the difference between virtual size and actual size.Do I need to do something more to increase the actual size? If so what is that?

Comment: Did you forget to extended the partition within the OS?  "What is the difference between virtual size and actual size" - virtual is how large the virtual HDD can store, the actual size is how large the virtual hdd file actually is.

Comment: Open Windows7 guest and extend system partition in it with Disk Management.